# StackOverflowExceptions in nested async methods on unwinding of the stack

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, stack-overflow

We have a lot of nested async methods and see behavior that we do not really understand. Take for example this simple C# console application

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var x = Test(index: 0, max: int.Parse(args[0]), throwException: bool.Parse(args[1])).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    
    static async Task<string> Test(int index, int max, bool throwException)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    
        if(index < max)
        {
            var nextIndex = index + 1;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"b {nextIndex} of {max} (on threadId: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})");
              
                return await Test(nextIndex, max, throwException).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"e {nextIndex} of {max} (on threadId: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})");
            }
        }
    
        if(throwException)
        {
            throw new Exception("");
        }
    
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When we run this sample with the following arguments:

> AsyncStackSample.exe 2000 false

We get a `StackOverflowException` and this is the last message we see in the console:

> e 331 of 2000 (on threadId: 4)

When we change the arguments into

> AsyncStackSample.exe 2000 true

We end with this message

> e 831 of 2000 (on threadId: 4)

So the `StackOverflowException` occurs on the unwinding of the stack (not really sure if we should call it that, but the `StackOverflowException` occurs after the recursive call in our sample, in synchronous code, a `StackOverflowException` will always occur on the nested method call). In the case that we throw an exception, the `StackOverflowException` occurs even earlier.

We know we can solve this by calling `Task.Yield()` in the finally block, but we have a few questions:

1. Why does the Stack grow on the unwinding path (in comparison to a
   method that doesn't cause a thread switch on the await)?
2. Why does the `StackOverflowException` occurs earlier in the Exception case than when we don't throw an exception?

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808166/recursion-and-the-await-async-keywords

Comment: Thanks @Bit , although it touches on the same topics, it doesn't answer our specific questions.

Comment: Also related, but I never gave the return journey much consideration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464468/async-recursion-where-is-my-memory-actually-going

Comment: I ran it and got the same results as you. When I removed the call to `await Task.Yield()` it unwound the stack all the way to the beginning. I then tried to increase the number of iterations by making the first argument 3000 and that threw the same exception on `e 1568 of 3000 (on threadId: 5)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Why does the Stack grow on the unwinding path (in comparison to a method that doesn't cause a thread switch on the await)?

The core reason is because [`await` schedules its continuations with the `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` flag](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html).

So, when the "innermost" `Yield` is executed, what you end up with is 3000 incomplete tasks, with each "inner" task holding a completion callback that completes the nextmost-inner task. This is all in the heap.

When the innermost `Yield` resumes (on a thread pool thread), the continuation (synchronously) executes the remainder of the `Test` method, which completes its task, which (synchronously) executes the remainder of the `Test` method, which completes *its* task, etc., a few thousand times. So, the call stack on that thread pool thread is actually *growing* as each task completes.

Personally, I find this behavior surprising and reported it as a bug. However, the bug was closed by Microsoft as "by design". It's interesting to note that the Promises specification in JavaScript (and by extension, the behavior of `await`) *always* has promise completions run asynchronously and *never* synchronously. This has confused some JS devs, but it is the behavior that I would expect.

Usually, it works out OK, and `ExecuteSynchronously` acts as a minor performance improvement. But as you noted, there are scenarios like "async recursion" where it can cause a `StackOverflowException`.

There *are* some [heuristics in the BCL to run continuations asynchronously if the stack is too full](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/07/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/), but they're just heuristics and don't always work.

> Why does the StackOverflowException occurs earlier in the Exception case than when we don't throw an exception?

That's a great question. I have no idea. :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Stephen. Any idea how to get the second question answered?

Comment: You could ask it as a separate question. That way it's very specific - just the one question.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/26567 seems to be the answer for the second question.