# How does C# detect a stack overflow?

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow

I was writing code to solve a problem and it worked with a small input, however when increasing to a larger input I got a stack overflow exception:

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 3239 times:
--------------------------------
   at Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Main>$>g__Traverse|3(Point, Direction)
--------------------------------
   at Program.<<Main>$>g__Do|0_0()
```

I also noticed that the number of times it claims to repeat varies between executions, sometimes I'd get ~2300 repeats or ~2800 repeats too.

After a while of debugging I could not find anything wrong with my code so I manually set the stack size of the thread to `Int32.MaxValue` and the code worked and produced the correct answer.

I am curious if anyone knows how C# goes about detecting a stack overflow? In this case, it seems to me that C# was prematurely predicting a stack overflow even though the program does terminate given the chance to.

Additionally, why would C# give a stack overflow error saying a call was repeated `x` times where `x` seems to vary each execution?

Any insights or information is appreciated!

Comment: You get a StackoverflowException _when the stack overflows_. No predictions made. For any further suggestions, show what you did (code).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror  Eventhough that question is tagged with Java, the principle is the same.

Comment: "I manually set the stack size of the thread to `Int32.MaxValue`" cool but I recommend that you don't do that and actually fix the code by eg switching to an iterative traversal using an explicit `Stack<T>` data structure.

Comment: A stackoverflow doesn't always mean there is something *wrong* with your code. It may just be, that it processes so much data (or has so many recursive calls) that the available stack isn't large enough and increasing the stacksize may make the error go away. But it *often*  is an indication for a runaway recursion.

Comment: I had someone mention once that a program can be terminated early if it is detected that the same state in a recursive call is seen many times, not sure how true this was but wanted to know a bit more about it! I held off on increasing the stack size manually because I do understand its not great practice, main reason I did that was to see if my code terminated. Next time I will try using a Stack<T> and a iterative approach :)

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Way to go from recursion to iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration).

Comment: _"I had someone mention once that a program can be terminated early if it is detected that the same state in a recursive call is seen many times"_ - that would be a detection made by the program itself as part of the algorithm, not the runtime and certainly not the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack is a contiguous chunk of memory† (of a defined and finite size) that is consumed (and usually released again promptly) by various operations including allocation of locals and transients, "stackalloc" buffers, etc. Recursive calls *usually* leave everything existing in place and allocate more data in the next space down, hence deeply recursive operations are prone to using large amounts of stack space.

There is no "prediction" going on here; you simply hit the end of the chunk of memory. This is not meant to happen, and means that your approach is doomed - usually: too recursive. It isn't usually important to guarantee that the stack will bottom out at exactly the same place every time, since you're already in a doomed scenario. That's like saying that an engine should blow up at exactly 87432rpm each time. A few minor variations might impact the *exact* space available or the *exact* space used in individual stack-frames, but overall: that doesn't matter, you've still used the wrong approach.

It might be nice if C# was better at tail-call recursion (which eliminates need to keep old frames), but without code we can't even see if your code is a *candidate* for tail-call.

If you have a deeply recursive scenario, you can usually work around the limits of the stack by moving the recursion **off the stack**. Usually this means using a `Queue<T>` or `Stack<T>` to hold your logical state, add the seed value to it, and then a simple `while` loop (while not empty) that takes the next value, does some thinking, and optionally adds some value or values back to be processed.

---

† virtual memory; chunks of which may or may not yet be mapped to real memory, but that doesn't matter

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did wonder about tail recursion and moved my recursive calls to the end of the function but because of the logic involved, I don't think that was happening. The problem I was working with really leaned towards using recursion, next time I will try your suggestion for using a loop with a Queue or Stack

Comment: There are some situations where `async` code run in a loop can overflow a stack, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44763436/14868997 This is unexpected and the code itself is not recursive.

Answer (score -5):

C#'s compiler detects stack overflow prematurely and stops the program. Your program may terminate successfully but the compiler can't take the risk of overflowing the memory stack. Please optimize your code. I know it might not be much helpful but the right way is to find a new way to solve your current problem.

You can go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=net-8.0) to learn how the overflow is handled by throwing an exception by c#

Comment: No compiler ever stopped any program. Prematurly or not.

Comment: Crashing the OS not counted.